# angular RouterReuseStrategy is not working for router with params

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I have two components called **A,B**. I need form data of **component B** when re-routed back from **component A**. So, I have implemented **RouterReuseStrategy**. But, it works fine only for router without params but failed to retrieve the form data for router with params.

**router-strategy.ts**

```
import {RouteReuseStrategy,ActivatedRouteSnapshot,DetachedRouteHandle,} from '@angular/router';

export class CustomRouteReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {
  private routeLeftFrom: string | undefined;
  private handlers: { [key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle } = {};

  shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    this.routeLeftFrom = route.routeConfig!.path;
    return route.data['shouldReuseRoute'] || false;
  }

  store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handler: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
    console.log('[router-reuse] storing handler');
    if (handler) {
      this.handlers[this.getUrl(route)] = handler;
    }
  }

  shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    var wasRoutePreviouslyDetached =
      !!this.handlers[route.url.join('/') || route.parent!.url.join('/')];
    if (wasRoutePreviouslyDetached) {
      var reuseRouteFromVerified =
        route.data['reuseRoutesFrom'].indexOf(this.routeLeftFrom) > -1;

      if (reuseRouteFromVerified) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle | null {
    if (!route.routeConfig || route.routeConfig.loadChildren) {
      return null;
    }

    return this.handlers[this.getUrl(route)];
  }

  shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,current: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    let reUseUrl = false;

    if (future.routeConfig) {
      if (future.routeConfig.data) {
        reUseUrl = future.routeConfig.data['reuse'];
      }
    }
    const defaultReuse = future.routeConfig === current.routeConfig;

    return reUseUrl || defaultReuse;
  }

  getUrl(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): string {
    if (route.routeConfig) {
      const url = route.routeConfig.path;
      console.log('[router-reuse] returning url', url);

      return url as string;
    }

    throw new Error('Route configuration is missing for the provided route.');
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {
  MatButtonModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatNativeDateModule,
} from '@angular/material';
import { PageAComponent } from './page-a/page-a.component';
import { PageBComponent } from './page-b/page-b.component';
import { PageCComponent } from './page-c/page-c.component';
import { RouteReuseStrategy, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CustomRouteReuseStrategy } from './router-strategy';

export let browserRefresh = false;

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'a', component: PageAComponent },
  // {
  //   path: 'b',
  //   component: PageBComponent,
  //   data: {
  //     shouldReuseRoute: true,
  //     reuseRoutesFrom: ['a'],
  //   },
  // },
  {
    path: 'b/:userID',
    component: PageBComponent,
    data: {
      shouldReuseRoute: true,
      reuseRoutesFrom: ['a'],
    },
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, PageAComponent, PageBComponent, PageCComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: RouteReuseStrategy,
      useClass: CustomRouteReuseStrategy,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Attaching [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-reactive-forms-validation-b4r5yu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpage-b%2Fpage-b.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Frouter-strategy.ts) for ref.

Solution I am looking for: **Need form data(in component B) after re-route from component A.The route should be with params.**

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Might help others. Attaching [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-reactive-forms-validation-r8pawo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpage-b%2Fpage-b.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Frouter-strategy.ts) ref.